# Play-Framework 2.4: Use Spring Depedency Injection with Play-Framework Instead of Guice

Tags: java, spring, playframework, dependency-injection, spring-data-mongodb

I am using `Spring-Depedency` injection instead of `Play-Framework Guice` Depedency injection, because of our requirement, we need to use most of the `Spring-Modules` in our application like `Spring-Data-Mongodb` etc. But the problem is that, our dependencies are not inject properly in controller like as below:

My Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"service", "controllers"})
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages="repository")
public class SpringDataMongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration{

private play.Configuration configuration = play.Configuration.root();

private MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions(){
    Builder builder = new Builder();
    builder.connectionsPerHost(configuration.getInt("connections-per-host"));
    builder.connectTimeout(configuration.getInt("connections-timeout"));
    builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(configuration.getInt("max-connections-idle-time"));
    builder.maxConnectionLifeTime(configuration.getInt("max-connections-life-time"));
    builder.minConnectionsPerHost(configuration.getInt("max-connections-per-host"));
    builder.socketKeepAlive(configuration.getBoolean("socket-keep-live"));
    builder.socketTimeout(configuration.getInt("socket-timeout"));
    return builder.build();
}

private ServerAddress serverAddress(){
    ServerAddress serverAddress = new ServerAddress(new InetSocketAddress(configuration.getString("mongodb.uri"), configuration.getInt("mongodb.port")));
    return serverAddress;
}

@Override
protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return configuration.getString("mongodb.dbname");
}

@Override
public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
    return new MongoClient(serverAddress(), mongoClientOptions());
}

@Override
protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
    return configuration.getString("package.scan");
}}
```

My `built.sbt` dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
javaJdbc,
cache,
javaWs,
"org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "4.1.6.RELEASE",
"org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-mongodb" % "1.7.2.RELEASE")

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
// routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator


fork in run := true
```

In `built.sbt`, i am commenting `routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator` for stop `Play Guice Dependency Injection`.

My route file:

```
# Home page
GET     /                           @controllers.Application.index()
```

When i run the application, i am getting following error:

```
- play.api.libs.concurrent.ActorSystemProvider - Starting application    default Akka system: application
- play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
********************************** userService : null
- application - 
! @6nbpln6jk - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
```

[image: play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[NullPointerException: null]]]

According to this error, Spring `@Autowire` annotation does not work properly. But i am not getting the reason, when spring `@Autowire` not worked? How could i resolve this issue?

Comment: This is an answer to a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/43440349/3563224

Answer (score 3):

This answer will not solve your problem but I hope it will guide you how to overcome your problem using a different approach. First of all, I'm using Spring integrated in Play however, Spring uses an abstraction class and handles its own life cycle for now. Play (2.4.*) uses its default Guice injection support.

For your problem, after my research I've found these links about replacing/integrating Spring's dependency injection with juice in Play 2.4. However, **integration with Spring for Play 2.4 doesn't exist yet**, there is only a prototype done by James Ropper as stated in this issue:

[github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4665](http://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4665)

[github.com/jroper/play-spring](http://github.com/jroper/play-spring)

[github.com/spring-projects/spring-guice](http://github.com/spring-projects/spring-guice)

Comment: Thanks @SerhatCan, i already checked `spring-guice`. But the problem is that, it act like a bridge between spring and Guice. The last development of this project done was 1 year ago. So, there is risk to used these in our live projects. But thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate play with Spring application i given step by step how to develop. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360579/using-spring-as-a-dependency-injection-framework-with-play-2-4-x/33035001#33035001)

Comment: In play 2.4 the `Global` file is deprecated.

Comment: I worked with 2.4.3 It is available. Here they removed one method. Just try my example it will work on 2.4 also.

Comment: my concern is about `Spring-Data` with play-framework and using Java Based configuration. According to your example. you just use `@inject` annotation and i am getting error using `@Autowire` annotation.

Comment: Yes, Autowire annotation we should not use outside of GlobalSetting file. Other than GlobalSettings file we need to use @Inject annotation.

Comment: the main problem with my application pattern and Java Based Configuration. When i use `@Inject` annotation, the google guice thrown an exception about could not find binding.

Answer (score 0):

May be a late answer for this question. Posting it for the benefit of future reference.

I faced a similar challenge of using spring beans in Play 2.5.X. There is an api **guice-spring** provided by guice to integrate spring with guice injector. Using this api I was able to configure guice to fetch beans form my spring context for injection, especially my controller beans. Check this [link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=s9Yr6gnhE90C&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=bind(BeanFactory.class).toInstance&source=bl&ots=-UgbWMazG0&sig=xWxo1KJ7rBZHpQyddUBfwvN1k8E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi609PisYXRAhWJLo8KHXxIDyIQ6AEIKDAD#v=onepage&q=bind(BeanFactory.class).toInstance&f=false) to see how to bind a spring bean into guice.